# How to purify pandas dataframe efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

It's hard for me to write my question to proper words, so thank you for reading my question.

I have a dataframe, and it has two columns, `high`, `low`, which record the 
 higher values and lower values.

For example:

```
     high   low
0     NaN   NaN
1   100.0   NaN
2     NaN  50.0
3   110.0   NaN
4     NaN   NaN
5   120.0   NaN
6   100.0   NaN
7     NaN   NaN
8     NaN  30.0
9     NaN   NaN
10    NaN  20.0
11    NaN   NaN
12  110.0   NaN
13    NaN   NaN
```

I want to merge the continuous ones (on the same side), and leave the highest (lowest) one.

"the continuous ones" means the values in the `high` column between two values in the `low` column, or the values in the `low` column between two values in the `high` column

The high values on index `3`, `5`, `6` should be merged, and the highest value on index `5` (the value `120`) should be left.

The low values on index `8`, `10` should be merged, and the lowest value on index `10` (the value `20`) should be left.

The result is like that:

```
     high   low
0     NaN   NaN
1   100.0   NaN
2     NaN  50.0
3     NaN   NaN
4     NaN   NaN
5   120.0   NaN
6     NaN   NaN
7     NaN   NaN
8     NaN   NaN
9     NaN   NaN
10    NaN  20.0
11    NaN   NaN
12  110.0   NaN
13    NaN   NaN
```

I tried to write a for loop to handle the data, but it was very slow when the data is large (more than 10,000).

The code is:

```py
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame(dict(high=[None,100,None,110,None,120,100,None,None,None,None,None,110,None],
                    low=[None,None,50,None,None,None,None,None,30,None,20,None,None,None]))
flag = None
flag_index = None
for i in range(len(data)):
    if not pd.isna(data['high'][i]):
        if flag == 'flag_high':
            higher = data['high'].iloc[[i, flag_index]].idxmax()
            lower = flag_index if i == higher else i
            flag_index = higher
            data['high'][lower] = None
        else:
            flag = 'flag_high'
            flag_index = i
    elif not pd.isna(data['low'][i]):
        if flag == 'flag_low':
            lower = data['low'].iloc[[i, flag_index]].idxmin()
            higher = flag_index if i == lower else i
            flag_index = lower
            data['low'][higher] = None
        else:
            flag = 'flag_low'
            flag_index = i
```

Is there any efficient way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why 30 gets removed even though its not consecutive

Comment: seems to be that it is between two values on the high column, and higher than the other entry

Comment: Thank you for comments. I updated my question.

Comment: @EricSun Do you mean by removing the highest value in the `low` column?

Comment: @EricSun I don't get anything now

Comment: @U9-Forward Not really. I want to leave only the lowest value in the `low` column between two values in the `high` column.

Comment: @EricSun What ya mean by leave, keep, or remove?

Comment: @U9-Forward Thank you for comments, and sorry for the troublesome question. I updated the question and I think it became more understandable now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a line oriented iterative processing like that, pandas usually does a bad job, or more exactly is not efficient at all. But you can always directly process the underlying numpy arrays:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=pd.DataFrame(dict(high=[None,100,None,110,None,120,100,None,None,None,None,None,110,None],
                    low=[None,None,50,None,None,None,None,None,30,None,20,None,None,None]))

npdata = data.values
flag = None
flag_index = None
for i in range(len(npdata)):
    if not np.isnan(npdata[i][0]):
        if flag == 'flag_high':
            if npdata[i][0] > npdata[flag_index][0]:
                npdata[flag_index][0] = np.nan
                flag_index = i
            else:
                npdata[i][0] = np.nan
        else:
            flag = 'flag_high'
            flag_index = i
    elif not np.isnan(npdata[i][1]):
        if flag == 'flag_low':
            if npdata[i][1] < npdata[flag_index][1]:
                npdata[flag_index][1] = np.nan
                flag_index = i
            else:
                npdata[i][1] = np.nan
        else:
            flag = 'flag_low'
            flag_index = i
```

In my test it is close to 10 times faster.

The larger the dataframe, the higher the gain: at 1500 rows, using directly numpy arrays is 30 times faster.

Comment: Can you add test in large dataframe, e.g. 1000 rows to answer?

Comment: @jezrael: please see my edit. The ratio seems to be stable for large dataframes, at 14000 it is still close to 30.

Comment: @jezrael: I have coded initial OP's code and my own in two functions, and I test them with `timeit.timeif('process(df.copy())', globals=globals(), number=n)` and I let n decrease when the size of the dataframe grows. I never use direct `time.clock()` for benchmarking but always rely on `timeit`

Comment: OK, it is maybe some way O never use it. Btw, here numpy is bad choice, because hard vectorized this. Need numba.

Comment: @jezrael: I have used Python for more than 10 years, pandas and numpy only for few months but still do not use numba... Here I only use numpy because it is the underlying data structure of pandas in order not to copy the data into plain Python structures. This simply avoids pandas spending time converting every row to a Series.

Comment: ya, only my friend advice :)

Comment: Thank you, I tested it and for a 233,184 rows data, it was 50 times faster.

Comment: BTW, `data.loc[:] = npdata` is needed for me

Comment: replacing `0` to `data.columns.get_loc('high')` and replacing `1` to `data.columns.get_loc('row')` is more readable!

Comment: I mean the `0` in `np.isnan(npdata[i][0]` :)